# Laravel, ошибка Bad Request после установки

Tags: laravel, apache

После установки laravel на openserver, появляется ошибка:

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.  
Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Установил laravel с помощью composer

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel name --prefer-dist
```

Как решить эту проблему?
htaccess настроены
Также есть установленная более ранняя версия laravel 5.3, она нормально работает на openserver.

Comment: а если вырубить опенсервер, а в корне проекта сделать `php artisan serve`?

Comment: @n.osennij, да, так запускается laravel, но почему не запускается через apache?

Comment: нашёл в чём была проблема. проблема была в том, что в названии сайта присутствовала точка `.`, т.е. при установке нужно было прописать название без точки